# C, reading multiple numbers from single input line (scanf?)

Tags: c, c99, scanf

I have written an app in C which expects two lines at input.
First input tells how big an array of int will be  and the second input contains values separated by space.
For example, the following input

```
5
1 2 3 4 99
```

should create an array containing `{1,2,3,4,99}`

What is the fastest way to do so? My problem is to read multiple numbers without looping through the whole string checking if it's space or a number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
int i, size;
int *v;
scanf("%d", &size);
v = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
for(i=0; i < size; i++)
    scanf("%d", &v[i]);
```

Remember to `free(v)` after you are done!

Also, if for some reason you already have the numbers in a string, you can use `sscanf()`

Comment: I thought it'll look for numbers separated by "\n"?

Comment: `%d` (as well as most % conversions, but not all of them) automatically skips any whitespace. Read the scanf documentation for details!

Comment: "If for some reason"?  You should never use `scanf` and should prefer using `fgets` with `sscanf`. http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: @jamesdlin, sorry, but I disagree. If you really *know* how to use scanf, you can use it safely. And by knowing I mean really understanding all options and conversions from scanf. (read the entire manpage)

Comment: The fact that it can leave unprocessed input in the input buffer should make you cringe.  Yes, there are ways you can use `scanf` safely, but all the hoops you have to jump through simply don't make it worthwhile.  `fgets` with `sscanf` is much simpler and has fewer gotchas for the uninitiated.

Comment: I agree. If the input is string in nature, `fgets` is the best option.

Comment: `scanf("%d"...` does not enforce anything about a _line_ of input per OP's title.  Should user input not be precisely formated as expected, this approach fails in  many ways with it lack of error detection.  OK for learners, but insufficient for good programming.

Answer (score 4):

Here 'N' is the number of array elements of Array 'A'

```
int N, A[N];
printf("Input no of element in array A: ");
scanf("%d", &N);
printf( "You entered: %d\n", N);
printf("Input array A elements in one line: ");
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
   fscanf(stdin, "%d", &A[i]);
   printf( "A[%d] is: %d\n", i, A[i]);
}
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by explaining how this answers OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example taken from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/ that I've adapted to our context.

It splits the str chain in sub chains and then I convert each part into an int. I expect that the entry line is numbers seperated by commas, nothing else. Size is the size of your array. You should do scanf("%d", &size); as Denilson stated in his answer. At the end, you have your int array with all values.

```
int main(){
  int size = 5, i = 0;
  char str[] ="10,20,43,1,576";
  int list[size];
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str,",");
  list[i] = atoi(pch);
  i++;
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
    if(pch != NULL)
      list[i] = atoi(pch);
    i++;
  }

  for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    printf("%d. %d\n",i+1,list[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` is kind of a pain in the neck.  Check out `strtol()` for this kind of problem, it will make your life very easy.

Comment: together with strtok it might be interesting, but I have no idea how to read the whole line at first ;/

Comment: @michal, `fgets()` will read a line.  I don't know why you would need `strtok()` for your problem.

Comment: strtol will give only first number. Thats not the purpose here right?

Comment: It only gives one number at a time, but that's easily solved with a loop.

Answer (score -2):

This code employs a straight forward approach of reading each character through getchar().We go onto reading a number util we find a blank space.The index 'i' of the array gets updated after that.This is repeated until newline('\n') is encountered

```
#include<iostream>
main()
{
  char ch;
  int arr[30] ;
  ch =getchar();
  int num = 0;
  int i=0;
  while(ch !='\n')
  {
    if(ch == ' ')
    { 
      arr[i] = num;
      i++;
      num = 0;
    }
    if(((ch -48) >=0) && (ch-48 <=9))
      num = (num*10) + (ch - 48);
    ch = getchar();   
  }
  arr[i] = num;
  for(int j=0;i<=i;j++)
     std::cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This approach fails when numbers are negative or begin with a `'+'`.  It is not C code.