# How to write in a list of numbers into a file using a for loop in C?

Tags: c, file-io

So I want to use a for loop to read in 10 different numbers into a text file. The problem with my program is that it crashes while inputting the 4th number. How do I fix this? Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  /* For exit() function */
int main()
{
   int x[20], i;
   FILE *fptr;
   fptr=fopen("line.txt","w");

   printf("Enter numbers\n");
   for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        gets(x[i]);
   }
   fprintf(fptr,"%d", x);
   fclose(fptr);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets()` ever. But, it happens to be inappropriate to use on an `int` array.

Comment: Did you read the [gets manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets) to see what it does and what the type of its argument is? And did you take any notice of the warnings given by your compiler?

Comment: Does it still crash after changing gets to scanf?  The biggest problem I see is the attempty to fprintf x (an array of int) to the file as if it were just an int. What you probably want is to loop through all 10 elements of x again and fprintf each one individually.

Comment: You're including `stdlib.h` 'for `exit()`', but I don't see you using `exit()` anywhere. If you don't end up using it, you can remove that `"include` directive and make your program a bit smaller. In `main()`, you can use `return` to achieve the same results as `exit()`. Calling `return 1;` from `main()` will achieve the same results as calling `exit(1):`. It is useful for exiting the program within a function however.

Comment: Please do not edit the question so as to make answers irrelevant/incorrect.  If you have somthig to add to your code, either APPEND the new version or ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `scanf`, don't use `gets`. `gets` is not safe to use in this manner, it reads a string, not a number. I woudl avoid `gets` anyway. Have a look at this answer on how to read integers....

[How to read numbers separated by space using scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425953/how-to-read-numbers-separated-by-space-using-scanf)

Answer (score 1):

You should use scanf

```
scanf("%d", x[i])
```

gets give your a string instead of an interger.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem though, after you edited with scanf, note `fprintf(fptr,"%d", x);` will not work as you expected, x is not an integer, it's an array of integers, so you need write each of the array into the file, you can use a loop to do this:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    fprintf(fptr,"%d", x[i]);
}
fclose(fptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

- In this, You are taking value one by one into array using `for` loop but can you observed that how you are printing array into file?
- You also need to `for` loop to print all the 10 value in file.

> ```
> int main()
> {
>   int x[20], i;
>   FILE *fptr; 
>   fptr = fopen("line.txt","w");
>   printf("Enter numbers\n");
>
>     for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
>     {
>       gets(x[i]);
>     }
>
>    for(i = 0; i < 10 ;i++)
>    {
>      fprintf(fptr,"%d", x[i]);
>    }
>   fclose(fptr);
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

- **Also you can do like this :**

> ```
>  int main()
> {
>   int x[20], i;
>   FILE *fptr; 
>   fptr = fopen("line.txt","w");
>   printf("Enter numbers\n");
>
>     for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
>     {
>       gets(x[i]);
>       fprintf(fptr,"%d", x[i]);
>     }
>   fclose(fptr);
>   return 0;
> }
> ```