# white space in format string of scanf()

Tags: c, input, output, scanf, whitespace

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter values of a and b\n");
    scanf(" %d%d ",&a,&b);
    printf("a=%d b=%d", a, b);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Here if I use scanf(), as in my code then the compiler expects the user to enter three values, I am unable to understand this , when i use scanf() without any white space then it asks for only two inputs as expected , so i am confused whats the difference between these two , plz explain ...

Comment: Do you mean the whitespace after the second `%d` or before the first one? Do you want to ignore the first or the third value?

Comment: i am asking for both , before first %d and after second %d , i just want to know that why the compiler asks for three inputs when i use a white space in scanf like in my code

Comment: The readable version of ignoring an input is to use `%*d`.

Comment: what should i do if i want to enter only two integers rather than three , for the same code with white space as mentioned in the question ????

Comment: `scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);` will read 2 integers and nothing more.

Comment: will scanf("  %d%d    ",&a,&b); always read 3 integers ???

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter values of a and b\n");
    scanf("%d\n%d",&a,&b);
    printf("a=%d b=%d", a, b);
    
    return 0 ;
}

Comment: Note that the leading whitespace in the format string is not needed since the `%d` directive _automatically_ ignores initial whitespace characters, and the trailing whitespace in the format string is a mistake which causes problems for interactive input.

Comment: @user3121023  can u please explain it more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give a space after your numbers, `scanf` must determine the end of the whitespaces to be matched:

```
scanf("%d ", &a);
```

Here the space means **read and discard *all* whitespaces**. A non-whitespace character (or EOF) must appear for `scanf` to make it clear what ***all*** is so they can be properly read and discarded.

Consider this input stream (dots are character indicators):

```
   1   2
........
```

If you call `scanf("%d")`, then after calling, the leftover stream is

```
   2
....
```

... where the whitespaces will be discarded **at next read**. Note the leading spaces are automatically discarded when reading the number.

If you call `scanf("%d ")` instead, the leftover stream is

```
2
.
```

You see the whitespaces are gone immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425953/how-to-read-numbers-separated-by-space-using-scanf).

You can use a space between the `%d`'s.
That will require from the user to input something like: `12 32` (with the spaces).

If you don't want that, you should use a loop with the scanf.

Good luck.

Comment: i am not asking about space between the two %d's , i am asking about the white space before and after my first and second %d in the scanf statement, how do they modify my program ?

Comment: A space between the `%d`s does not change anything. A whitespace means "ignore all whitespaces", but a `%d` also ignores all whitespaces.