# Read user input "string" and "int" in one line separated by space (C)

Tags: c, user-input

I have some functions like push, pop, delete etc. for a singly linked list and implemented the following function to get user input:

```
void user_input(){
char input[10];
while(fgets(input, 9, stdin)){
    if(strncmp(input, "add", 3) == 0){
        int x;
        printf("Number to add: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        push(x);
        printf("%d added.\n", x);
    }
    else if(strncmp(input, "del", 3) == 0){
        int x;
        printf("Number to delete: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        delete(x);
        printf("%d deleted.\n", x);
    }
    else if(strncmp(input, "q", 1) == 0){
        printf("Program terminated.\n");
        break;
    }
    // and some other if else statements...
}
```

So I can input a string like "add", then strncmp will compare it and I get another prompt asking me to enter the number I want to add and stores in x using scanf. Something like this:

```
add
Number to add: 5
5 added.
```

However I am looking for a way to be able to enter something like this:

```
add 5
del 2
etc.
```

Basically a string and int value in one line separated by space, instead of writing "add" first, pressing enter and writing the number. I tried using sscanf but had no luck yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read numbers separated by space using scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425953/how-to-read-numbers-separated-by-space-using-scanf)

Comment: What I normally do is (1) read whole lines using `fgets` or the equivalent, (2) break up the line into whitespace-separated "words". (3) use `strcmp` or the equivalent on the first word to decide what to do, and (4) use `atoi` or the equivalent on words that I want to treat as numbers.  Obviously (2) is the slightly tricky part.  Library functions like `strtok` can help, but you still have to do some work.  I find it useful to write one function that does all the work. See [here](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10h.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @SteveSummit I figured it out exactly as you suggested with help of the answer posted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier to step past input errors if you use `fgets` and then `sscanf`. You simply read another input string instead of messing around unblocking the input when invalid data was entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void push(int x) {
}

void delete(int x) {
}

void triple(int x, int y, int z) {
}

int main(void) 
{
    char input[100];
    char oper[20];
    int x, y, z;        // romantic expansion for more than one argument
    int res;
    int err;

    while(1) {
        err = 0;
        if(fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) != NULL) {
            res = sscanf(input, "%19s%d%d%d", oper, &x, &y, &z);

            if(res == 2 && strcmp(oper, "add") == 0){
                push(x);
                printf("%d added.\n", x);
            }
            else if(res == 2 && strcmp(oper, "del") == 0) {
                delete(x);
                printf("%d deleted.\n", x);
            }
            else if(res == 4 && strcmp(oper, "trip") == 0) {  // fantasy
                    triple(x, y, z);
                printf("%d %d %d tripled.\n", x, y, z);
            }
            else if(res == 1 && strcmp(oper, "q") == 0){
                printf("Program terminated.\n");
                break;
            }
            // some other if else statements...

            else {
                err = 1;
            }
        }

        else {
            err = 1;
        }

        if(err) {
            printf("Bad operation.\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `scanf()` like

```
char str[10];
int c;
if( scanf("%9s %d", str, &c)!=2 )
{
    perror("Something went wrong.");
}
```

The width for `%s` is one less than the size of `str`. The extra character is for the `\0`.

`scanf()` returns the number of successful assignments that it made which in this case should be `2`.

Now if you enter an input like

```
del 2
```

`str` will have `"del"` and `c` will have `2`.

Comment: Thanks I did already, but couldn't get it to work with a while loop, but I finally did it with sscanf :)

Answer (score 1):

A good strategy for what are trying to do would be:

1. Read the input line by line.
2. Process each line.
3. Continue until there is no input or the user chose to quit.

---

Here's the core outline.

```
// Make LINE_SIZE big enough for your needs
#define LINE_SIZE 100

void processLine(char line[]);    

int main()
{
   char line[LINE_SIZE];
   while ( fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, stdin) != NULL )
   {
      processLine(line);
   }
}


void processLine(char line[])
{
}
```

In `processLine`, your first job is to pull the command. Do the needful based on the command.

```
void processLine(char line[])
{
    char command[20];
    int num = 0;

    // Read the command and gather the number of characters read
    // This allows you to read more data from (line + num)
    int n = sscanf(line, "%19s%n", command, &num);
    if ( n != 2 )
    {
       // Problem
       exit(0);
    }

    // The command is to quit, exit.
    if ( isQuitCommand(command) )
    {
       exit(0);
    }

    char* commandData = line + num;
    if ( isAddCommand(command) )
    {
       processAdd(commandData);
    }
    else if ( isDeleteCommand(command) )
    {
       processDelete(commandData);
    }
    else { ... }
}
```

---

Here's a version of the program with stubs used for couple of functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Make LINE_SIZE big enough for your needs
#define LINE_SIZE 100

void processLine(char line[]);    

int isQuitCommand(char command[]);

int isAddCommand(char command[]);

int isDeleteCommand(char command[]);

void processAdd(char commandData[]);

void processDelete(char commandData[]);


int main()
{
   char line[LINE_SIZE];
   while ( fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, stdin) != NULL )
   {
      processLine(line);
   }
}


void processLine(char line[])
{
   char command[20];
   int num = 0;

   // Read the command and gather the number of characters read
   // This allows you to read more data from (line + num)
   int n = sscanf(line, "%19s%n", command, &num);
   if ( n != 2 )
   {
      // Problem
      exit(0);
   }

   // The command is to quit, exit.
   if ( isQuitCommand(command) )
   {
      exit(0);
   }

   char* commandData = line + num;
   if ( isAddCommand(command) )
   {
      processAdd(commandData);
   }
   else if ( isDeleteCommand(command) )
   {
      processDelete(commandData);
   }
   else
   {
      // ...
   }
}

int isQuitCommand(char command[])
{
   return (command[0] == 'q');
}

int isAddCommand(char command[])
{
   return (strcmp(command, "add") == 0);
}

int isDeleteCommand(char command[])
{
   return (strcmp(command, "del") == 0);
}

void processAdd(char commandData[])
{
   // Add code to process commandData
}

void processDelete(char commandData[])
{
   // Add code to process commandData
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer and useful information. It's a little more than what I have intended to do but the information are very useful and I will keep them in mind for the next time :)